# Как разрешить использовать стороннюю библиотеку

Tags: java, android

ошибка такая

```
Failed to resolve: es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0
```

Я в новый проект в android studio добавляю  `implementation 'es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0'`

и у меня

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 673 ms
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/voghdev/pdfviewpager/library/1.1.0/library-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
```

Да может еще дело за перехода
jcenter()
на

mavenCentral()

jcenter() работало

Comment: jcenter закрылся, а библиотека заброшена автором и новых публикаций в mavencentral он не делал. Клонируйте её с гитхаба и подключайте локальным модулем. Но подозреваю что она сильно отстала от жизни и придётся попотеть, чтобы она заработала.

Comment: она до сих пор работает для меня нормально в   jcenter есть какая информация как  клонировать и почему с гитхаба ?

Comment: Потому что её исходники лежат на гитхабе: https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager. Как вариант, можете попробовать подключить через jitpack (если он смог собрать её правильно) https://jitpack.io/#voghDev/PdfViewPager/1.1.2 см. How To

Comment: Большое спасибо  я  подключил через jitpack (подскажите если автор удалит проект с гит ) все перестанет работать ? есть ли возможность сделать архив и поместить в папку libs?

Comment: вернее как сделать такой архив

Comment: У проекта куча форков - если автор удалит свой репозиторий, остальные никуда не денутся. И jitpack хранит сборки в своём репозитории пока их не перестанут скачивать. AAR можете скачать с того же jitpack https://jitpack.io/com/github/voghDev/PdfViewPager/1.1.2/PdfViewPager-1.1.2.aar